# Attributeerror group().split() Бот должен принять и обработать два числа, но после получения первого падает с ошибкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Бот должен принять и обработать два числа, но после получения первого падает с ошибкой. Если заранее ввести два числа то все норм работает.

```
@Bot.inline_handler(func=lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)

def query_text(query):

try:

   digits_pattern = re.compile(r"^[0-9]+ [0-9]+$", re.MULTILINE)

matches = re.match(digits_pattern, query.query)

except AttributeError as ex:

 return 
num1, num2 = matches.group().split()

try:

m_sum = abs(float(num1) - (float(num2) / 100))

 r_sum = types.InlineQueryResultArticle(

 id='1', title="Ваш стоп",

        description="Результат: {!s}".format(m_sum),
        input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
            message_text="Обязательно поставь! {!s}".format(num1, num2, m_sum))
    )
    m_sum1 = abs(float(num1) + 50)
    r_sum1 = types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id='2', title="Text

        description="Результат: {!s}".format(m_sum1),
        input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
            message_text="{!s} + {!s} = {!s}".format(num1, num2, m_sum1))
    )

    Bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, [r_sum, r_sum1], cache_time=2147483646)

except Exception as e:
    print("{!s}\n{!s}".format(type(e), str(e)))
```

Bot.polling(none_stop=True)

***Ошибка:***

```py
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/TelegramBot.py
2020-04-05 15:00:43,157 (util.py:66 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "AttributeError occurred, args=("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/TelegramBot.py", line 24, in query_text
    num1, num2 = matches.group().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/TelegramBot.py", line 49, in <module>
    Bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 392, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 416, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 109, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/TelegramBot.py", line 24, in query_text
    num1, num2 = matches.group().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код в порядок. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Также было бы неплохо привести пример данных (сообщений), на которых возникает ошибка.

Comment: Когда регулярное выражение не находит совпадений, в matches попадает None. Отсюда ошибка. Нужно проверять что у вас в matches, и если None, то как-то обрабатывать эту ситуацию.

Comment: Можно пример, как обрабатывать эту ситуацию. Буду благодарен